# How to create custom property on object using Apache Chemistry

Tags: cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I'm working with a local instance of Alfresco CMS and I'm using the Apache Chemistry Java CMIS.
Everything works well for browsing and creating objects, however I'm having a hard time adding metadata on documents.

There is an example on their source page code saying that you need to call `updateProperties` on the `CmisObject`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, the exception I got stating: `Property 'my:property' is not valid for this type or one of the secondary types`

Do you know how can I add a custom property? Do I have to enhance the existing aspects collection and if so, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Property 'my:property' is not valid for this type or one of the secondary types

my:property seems to be a custom property, and should then be handled with a custom Alfresco aspect.

If you want to use Alfresco aspects, you will need the [Alfresco OpenCMIS Extension](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/opencmis-ext-creating-aspects.html)

The following code fragment allows to use the Alfresco Extension with OpenCMIS:

```
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();
// user credentials
parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "admin");
parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "admin");

// connection settings
parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom");
parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());

// set the alfresco object factory
parameter.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS, "org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl");

// create session
SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Session session = factory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0).createSession();
```

The following code allows to create a new document with a custom property filled :

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "doc1");
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document,my:docProps");
properties.put("my:property", "My document");

Document doc = session.getRootFolder().createDocument(properties, null, null);
```

Comment: thanks, but how do you define my:docProps? I got this exception when calling createDocument with your code: Type 'cmis:document,my:docProps' is unknown!

Comment: Properties are not dynamically assigned to a document in Alfresco. You need to add custom aspect in Alfresco. It's completely unlinked to cmis.

Comment: I've updated my answer: you need to install Alfresco OpenCmis Extension and declare the AlfrescoObjectFactory implementation before creating the session with Alfresco

Comment: I would said that it is more customization (xml) than configuration (in the UI). Check the following links to learn how to add new aspects : http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2010/02/25/adding-custom-aspect-support-in-alfresco-share/ and http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Ftasks%2Fkb-define-custom-model.html

Answer (score 1):

Custom properties should be defined in the repository and then you can try to set them in CMIS properties.