# Custom properties on documents using DotCmis and OpenKM

Tags: c#, dotcmis, openkm

Related to [creating custom property using alfresco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217036/how-to-create-custom-property-on-object-using-apache-chemistry), I am trying to set custom property on a document using DotCmis and OpenKM and I receive the error: `Property +'okp:contract.cups' is not valid for this type!`

How can I set a custom property using DotCmis and OpenKM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you ask this question at forum.openkm.com is the oficial channel where the OpenKM developers helps community users.

However take a look at this url:
http://wiki.openkm.com/index.php/Property_Groups_definition ( here some example )
http://wiki.openkm.com/index.php/Property_Groups_administration
http://wiki.openkm.com/index.php/Form_Element_description ( complete information about form element types )

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I also created the groups. Still no result. But I will also ask on forum.openkm.com.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and asked about it on the OpenKM-Forums. Sadly, as of now they still did not implement this feature. We worked around the problem by just posting our documents to different folders, depending on what type of document you are dealing with.